# How to use cordova plugins which are installed and activated in cordova plugins section?

Tags: appery.io

I am using ionic 5. I saw and activated cordova application in cordova plugins section (apple plugin). But when I go in create new - from plugin section, I cant see it. How can I use it?

Answer (score 1):

Only predefined Appery.io plugins are available in Create new->From plugin. Cordova plugins are something different.

See the documentation on how to use Cordova plugins in Ionic 5 projects: https://docs.appery.io/docs/ionic-5-solutions#using-native-apis-from-ionic

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about `cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple` available in Appery.io list of Core Cordova plugins, here is a video describing how to use it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9e8DvHBlKI

Comment: This is not actual. As I said this plugin is missing there now in ionic 5

Comment: @Shokolad Seems it is fixed now. With "Create New > From Plugin" I can see "Security > Login with Apple" plugin